# Why isn't the eigenvalue equal to the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $M$ and $x$ be the corresponding eigenvector.

Now,

\begin{align*}
Mx &= \lambda x \\
Mxx^{-1} &= \lambda xx^{-1} \\
MI &= \lambda I \\
\implies M &= \lambda \\
\end{align*}

It seems like this is a very elementary mistake. It definitely is wrong, but I can't see the problem with it.

Comment: The problem is the inverse of the vector which isn't defined

Comment: Ah, so my second step is already invalid. Thank you!

Comment: No problem ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although $MI=M$, it is not true that $\lambda I = \lambda$.

$\lambda I$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, while $\lambda$ is a number.